# Go: How does this hash function range from 0-32 bits?

Tags: hash, go

I'm trying to write my own hash function that uses a 30-bit hash.

Here is some code for a FNVa 32-bit hash.

```
func fnva32(data string) uint32 {
    var hash uint32 = 2166136261
    for _, c := range data {
        hash ^= uint32(c)
        hash *= 16777619 
    }
    return hash
}
```

Now here is my code that converts lowercase letters a-z into a 30-bit hash:

```
func id(s string) uint {
    var id uint
    var power uint = 1
    for _, c := range s {
        id+=(uint(c)-96)*power
        power*=26
    }
    return id%1073741824
}
```

That specifically limits my hash function to a maximum of 30-bit because I'm using a modulus against that number. But how is that FNVa32 hash limited to 32-bits? They are not using a modulus. How does it not generate a number larger than that?

Also you probably notice that I'm not using prime numbers. I tried some prime numbers but it increased the collisions. Currently I'm getting 291 collisions and FNVa32 is getting 76 collisions, from hashing 600,000 (real) words.

My question is... what is making FNVa32 limit to 32-bit, and how would I change it to be 30-bit instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the data type `uint32` is what limits the value to 32 bits. You can take any 32-bit number and shift right twice: `n >> 2` to get a 30-bit number, but it's still stored as 32 bits in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of the fnva32 function is uint32 so there is no way it could return an answer with more bits.  Also, the calculation uses a uint32 variable internally.

Comment: But... surely when it goes out of bounds then it's limited to the max, so then many of the hashes would be the same?

Comment: @Alasdair When the hash function goes out of bounds, which should happen every other time, it isn't being capped, it simply overflows and the highermost digits are discarded. It's like if you compute 256 * 256 (which equals 65536) and you only take the last three digits you don't get 999, you get 536.

Comment: Interesting... I tested and I do see that `uint32(4294967295) + 500 = 499`

Comment: Welcome to [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), which is how integers work in a lot of languages.